# Angular Universal Production Build Process

Tags: angular, angular-cli, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular10

I'm using Angular Universal 10 and I want to prerender my site.

I'm confused on the proper build process for a production environment.

Angular gives these two commands:

```
"build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run my-app.spa:server:production",
"prerender": "ng run my-app.spa:prerender"
```

Is it enough to just do this to get a production ready output?

```
npm run prerender
```

Or do I need to run both of these?

```
npm run build:ssr
npm run prerender
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand the difference between these two commands, run one and look at the compiled output.

The first command `npm run build:ssr` will compile your site into a file that can be served using a NodeJS Express app, as you see in `server.ts`. This way you will still only have one index.html file, but depending on your route, universal will deliver a rendered html file for that route to the browser. So, you are rendering on the server, *server-side rendering*.

The second command `npm run prerender` will use the `server.ts` to "pre-render" each of the routes with their own individual index.html file, all placed in a directory structure according to your routes. The compiled code looks like a traditional static website. So, you are rendering before you deploy, *pre-rendering*.

So which is best for you?

`build:ssr`

- advantage: You don't need to redeploy if content is created dynamically
- disadvantage: server has to be running a reliable and fast NodeJS process at all times. The good news is there are lots of ways to do this, e.g., serverless functions, app engine, etc.

`prerender`

- advantage: your app can be hosted on a regular http server
- disadvantage: you will probably need to redeploy when new content pages are added

[This post on Medium](https://medium.com/dvt-engineering/angular-universal-server-side-rendering-and-pre-rendering-for-angular-9-applications-f311e8f545bb) has a pretty good overview with more detailed information.

Comment: So the prerender command does build a production ready output, right? Also, if a page isn't prerendered then it will still get served by the Universal engine?

Comment: Yes, it will be a production build if your angular.json specifies so. I think prerender is set to be prod by default. If you look at the compiled .html files from the prerender, you might not see every single route as an individual file. That is okay, It means that some of your routes are dynamic and the prerendered build will still have those pages, through the SPA functionality.